# Print PDF file in PHP using sockets

Tags: php, pdf, printing

I want to print PDF file using sockets (because of script speed). I found this on other thread:

```
<?php 
if(($conn = fsockopen('192.168.10.112',9100,$errno,$errstr))===false){
    echo 'Connection Failed' . $errno . $errstr;
}

$data = <<<HERE
    ^XA
    ^FT50,200
    ^A0N,200,200^FDTEST^FS
    ^FT50,500
    ^A0N,200,200^FDZebra Printer^FS
    ^XZ
HERE;

#send request
$fput = fputs($conn, $data, strlen($data));

#close the connection
fclose($conn);
?>
```

How to print PDF file using this method?

Answer (score 0):

What it appears you're doing here is connecting directly to a network printer.

You should be able to print a file this way. Lets say you have `file.pdf`, then you can do this:

```
fputs($conn, file_get_contents('file.pdf'), filesize('file.pdf'));
```

Comment: Hi Mike.k, have you tested this code using a Zebra printer? or do you have a referal code to do it?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a Zebra printer, but if it supports network printing, it should work. Have you tried putting together the above code with a PDF and your printer's IP address?

Comment: @mike.k did you solve the riddle? I'm facing the same issue and for me this solution is not working. Do I need to change settings at the printer or do I need to send some extra "flags" with the connection?

Comment: @dj_thossi just did it with a network printer I have, worked perfectly. This printer is a Brother HL-3210CW.

Comment: @mike.k Thank you for your support. I got it to work. The printer needed to get some configurations send via ZPL commands to activate PDF printing via Socket. On the screen of the printer, it is not configurable, only via command. Thanks again